# Trouble with DateTime in PHP 5.4.11

Tags: php

Im using the code below in PHP 5.3, but now i have to run it on 5.4.11 and it does not work. No errors on page, and i got 500 error. If i comment the last 3 lines, everything is OK.

```
$sql = "*****";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or die('Error selecting date range.');
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$firstDate = $row['min'];
$lastDate = $row['max'];
$arrDates = array();
$date1 = new DateTime($firstDate);
$date2 = new DateTime($lastDate);
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
```

EDIT1: var_dump for $firstDate and $lastDate, impossible to get one for $date1 and $date2 as everything stops the moment i uncomment the objects.

```
$firstDate - string(10) "2013-01-27"
$lastDate - string(10) "2013-02-06"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A clue? perhaps a var_dump() of the values returned in $firstDate and $lastDate?

Comment: could you please print the contents of `$firstDate` and `$lastDate?`

Comment: Do some debugging, logging, log checking. We do not have enough details to answer this either. There is an error being produced somewhere, look for where to find it.

Comment: @MarkBaker - var_dump added in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found in the past that it is more reliable to use the static `createFromFormat` method to generate DateTime objects if you know the format of your input string in advance:

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $firstDate);
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $lastDate);
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
```

Comment: Perfect, but why is not the other code working? Any ideas?

Comment: No, I first experienced it with code that worked perfectly on Ubuntu but fell over on a Mac, same PHP version. I still can't explain it :(